# SQL count value per day return error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this dataset

```
dia valor valor_b
=== ===== =======
1    1     b1
1    2     b2
1    1     b3
1    2     b3
2    1     b2
2    3     b1
2    1     b1
2    1     b1
2    1     b2
1    3     b3
5    1     b4
5    3     b1
```

I need count how many times appear `valor_b` per day. And show in this structure:

```
valor dia_1 dia_2 dia_3 dia_4 dia_5
===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====
1     2     4     0     0     1
2     2     0     0     0     0
3     1     1     0     0     1
```

First time i do this to show the `value_b`

```
SELECT valor, 
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=1, valor_b, NULL)) dia_1,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=2, valor_b, NULL)) dia_2,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=3, valor_b, NULL)) dia_3,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=4, valor_b, NULL)) dia_4,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=5, valor_b, NULL)) dia_5
FROM test
GROUP BY valor;
```

But now counting `valor_b` *phpmyadmin* returns this error

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

And this is the used sentence

```
SELECT valor, 
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=1, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_1,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=2, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_2,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=3, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_3,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=4, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_4,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=5, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_5
    FROM test
    GROUP BY valor;
```

Comment: You can't nest aggregate functions.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh ok, and how i do it?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This may prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no concatenated strings in your results. So why use `GROUP_CONCAT` at all? Don't you simply want:

```
select
  valor,
  sum(dia = 1) as dia_1,
  sum(dia = 2) as dia_2,
  sum(dia = 3) as dia_3,
  sum(dia = 4) as dia_4,
  sum(dia = 5) as dia_5
from test
group by valor
order by valor;
```

This makes use of true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL.

I am not sure what `"I need count how many times appear valor_b per day"` is supposed to mean exactly. Count records where `valor_b` is not null? Then you'd have to add this to the expression:

```
  sum(dia = 1 and valor_b is not null) as dia_1,
```

etc.

Comment: @ReclutaPatoso: Good question. "I need count how many times appear valor_b per day".  So `valor_b` itself is not supposed to be in the results, only the count. You are right, this is not necessarily the row Count when `valor_b` can be null. You should clarify.

Comment: I've updated my answer hoping to have guessed what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correct

```
SELECT valor, 
      sum(IF(dia=1, 1, NULL)) dia_1,
      sum(IF(dia=2, 1, NULL)) dia_2,
      sum(IF(dia=3, 1, NULL)) dia_3,
      sum(IF(dia=4, 1, NULL)) dia_4,
      sum(IF(dia=5, 1, NULL)) dia_5
    FROM test
    GROUP BY valor;
```

Comment: You get it in the end. That `sum(IF(dia=1, 1, NULL))` means that each time we hit dia = 1 we add 1 to sum. As with each dia we have a valor_b assosiated we get a count of valor_b in the end!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `group_concat` here, a `sum` alone should suffice

```
SELECT  valor, 
        sum(IF(dia=1, 1, 0)) dia_1,
        sum(IF(dia=2, 1, 0)) dia_2,
        sum(IF(dia=3, 1, 0)) dia_3,
        sum(IF(dia=4, 1, 0)) dia_4,
        sum(IF(dia=5, 1, 0)) dia_5
FROM    test
GROUP BY valor
```

Comment: For day 1, for example, you count `valor_b` by summing a `1` for each row where the day is 1, and the same for the other days. Have you tried if this query returns you the expected results?